# Webbrowser out of date VB

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to access subwaylistens.com to complete a survey automatically, however when loading the web browser in VB-Web Browser, it states that the web browser is out of date"

I've tried creating a new value registry however this didn't work

```
 WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("https://subwaylistens.com/?subwaylistens&mkt=en-us&priv=1&con=1&tou=1"))
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

Comment: Either find out how that particular website does version or feature detection (but that'll be your job, not something you can ask people to do for you here on SO) or you're just going to have to fill in surveys like everybody else. Or, of course, stop using VB-Web browser and use something a little more up to date like selenium/phantom instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the following in is a c# code I hope it will help you

```
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int BrowserVer, RegVal;

        // get the installed IE version
        using (WebBrowser Wb = new WebBrowser())
            BrowserVer = Wb.Version.Major;

        // set the appropriate IE version
        if (BrowserVer >= 11)
            RegVal = 11001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 10)
            RegVal = 10001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 9)
            RegVal = 9999;
        else if (BrowserVer == 8)
            RegVal = 8888;
        else
            RegVal = 7000;

        // set the actual key
        using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            if (Key.GetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe") == null)
                Key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe", RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
```